# trouble with inheritance, classes?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, text

i am creating a text based adventure game in c++, This is my player class, i started with the health, stamina and Keys parameters and it was working fine.

```
class Player
    {
    public:
        Player();

        Player(int health, int stamina, int keys, Items weapon, Items armour, Items gold);

        void setHealth(int healthParam);
        int getHealth() const;

        void setStamina(int staminaParam);
        int getStamina() const;

        void setKeys(int keysParam);
        int getKeys() const;

        void setWeapon(Items weaponParam);
        Items getWeapon() const;

        void setArmour(Items armourParam);
        Items getArmour() const;

        void setGold(Items goldParam);
        Items getGold() const;

    private:
        int health;
        int stamina;
        int keys;
        Items weapon;
        Items armour;
        Items gold;

    };
```

I then created a class called items(below) and i want my player to inherit the variables from that class

```
class Items
{
public:
    Items();

    void setWeapon(string weaponParam);
    string getWeapon() const;

    void setArmour(string armourParam);
    string getArmour() const;

    void setGold(int goldParam);
    int getGold() const;

private:
    string weapon;
    string armour;
    int gold;

};

#endif
```

As you can see, i have an overloaded constructor in my player class, and i want player to take the attributes weapon, armour and gold, but in my main i am having a problem(main below)

```
int currentKeys = 0;
string userInput;

Player player(100, 100, currentKeys, "", "", 0);
```

the error i am getting is telling me i have no instance of the constructor that matched the  one in my player class, i just want to know if anyone can help me out with my problem? All my attributes are initially set to 0 or "" in the case of strings, so im not sure what to do, thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see a constructor for `Player` that takes `(int, int, int, char*, char*, int)`

Comment: How is a string literal("") convertible to `Items`?

Comment: This is inheritance abuse. Is a player really an Item? A player has an item is more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem pretty confused. This has nothing to do with inheritance. This is composition.

Each object of type `Items` will have the `weapon`, `armour`, and `gold` members. Your `Player` class has *three* objects of type `Items`. That means it has three lots of `weapon`, `armour`, and `gold`. I'm fairly sure you want your `Player` to only have one set of `Items`. So change:

```
Items weapon;
Items armour;
Items gold;
```

To just:

```
Items items;
```

Now get your `Player` constructor to take only a single `Items` object:

```
 Player(int health, int stamina, int keys, Items items);
```

It should initialize the member `items` with this argument. Now you can create your `Player` like so:

```
Items items;
items.setWeapon("Battle Axe");
items.setArmour("Gold Chest Plate");
items.setGold(10);
Player player(10, 20, 1, items);
```

However, I would recommend getting rid of the setter functions in `Items` and just letting it have a constructor which you would use like this:

```
Items items("Battle Axe", "Gold Chest Plate", 10);
Player player(10, 20, 1, items);
```

---

An alternate design would be to get rid of the `Items` class entirely and just make `weapon`, `armour`, and `gold` members of `Player`:

```
int health;
int stamina;
int keys;
std::string weapon;
std::string armour;
int gold;
```

Then the constructor should look like this:

```
Player(int health, int stamina, int keys, std::string weapon, std::string armour, int gold);
```

Comment: The second option seems a lot better than the first. I'm not sure what value the `Items` class has.

Comment: @john Perhaps the set of `Items` can exist independently of `Player`s.

Comment: Well maybe, but why group them? Seems a bit arbitrary to me. Anyway the OP knows, it's his world. He just needs to create classes that are natural for the game he's creating.

Comment: Thanks so much, we've only started this stuff in college so im still not 100% on a few things, but this cleared it up for me :) Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create an Items constructor

```
Items(string weapon, string armour, int gold);
```

And change your player constructor to

```
Player(int health, int stamina, int keys, Items items);
```

You can then aggregate `Items` in `Player`.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is right, no matching constructor.

You used:

```
Player(int,int,int,const char*,const char*,int)
```

which is not the same as:

```
Player(int,int,int,Item,Item,Item)
```

in your header